# ASP.NET DataReader values

Tags: asp.net

Is there a way of viewing the values inside a DataReader in Visual Studio.  Please note that I am referring the watch window when debugging.  For example, if there are two fields inside the datareader i.e. ID and Name, is there a way to view the values? When I hover above the DataReader, it just tells me what type of object it is i.e. a datareader.

Answer (score 3):

You can view both columns and data in the `reader` as below:

**To view columns**: Quick watch to the reader > Result View > [0], [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MdP79.jpg)...[expand any index] > Non-Public members > _schemainfo > [0], [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MdP79.jpg)...[expand any index], this will show you column name and data type.

**To view data**: Quick watch to the reader > Result View > [0], [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MdP79.jpg)...[expand any index] > Non-Public members > _values > [0], [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MdP79.jpg)...[expand any index], this will show you data present at the columns.

**Edit**:
*Column Information View*
[image: ColumnView]

*Data View for columns*
[image: DataView]

**Update:** data also can see as below way:

```
if (reader.HasRows)
{
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        int Id = Convert.ToInt32(reader["ID"]);
        string Name = Convert.ToString(reader["Name"]);
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: There is no results view under the DataReader.  There is: depth,fieldcount,hasrows,isclosed,recordsaffected and visible field count.

Comment: Which .NET Framework version are you using, I'm using 4.0, so far it is also available from 3.0, thanks for your time, thanks for your time.

Comment: I am trying the view the values inside the datareader using the watch window (without having to qrite more code).  I am using version 3.5.  Thanks.

Comment: I have opened QuickWatch and added the DataReader, however there is no option for Static Members, so I cannot expand it (as in your screen shot).  I am using Visual Studio Professional Edition 2008.

Comment: Oh! I'm using Visual Studio 2010, would you please try with that, thanks for your time.

Comment: Never mind.  Does anyone know of this is possible in VisualStudio 2008?

Answer (score 3):

You can't do that due to the nature of DataReader: it does not store the actual data, just some sort of "pointer" to the database.

To have the Reader be filled with data, you must call its `Read()` method - this will populate the object with the values of the next record, if available then return `true` otherwise it will return `false` and the data won't be available.

In the *watch* window of Visual Studio you should be able to dynamically execute that `Read()` method - just type `reader.Read()` and see the result - then to read the current values just write `reader[0]` and `reader[1]` in the *watch* window.

Anyhow, none of this is possible just from the tooltip, only in the special watch window.

Answer (score 1):

You can type `reader["ID"]` and `reader["Name"]` to view the value in watch window.

Comment: When I try this it says: cannot convert id to SQLDataReader.

Comment: I am trying to view the values in the watch window, therefore without writing code.  Thanks.